# Не получается отформатировать дату

Tags: java, spring, дата

Приходит строка такого вида :

```
Mon Aug 10 09:31:03 MSK 2020
```

Я хочу преобразовать её к такому виду:

```
2020-08-08 04:31
```

Используя форматтер :

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

В данный момент получаю ошибки , связанные с проблемой парсинга входных данных,если пытаться преобразовать строку в класс LocalDateTime...

Comment: Ну наверное стоит приложить те самые ошибки которые вы получаете, чтоб вам проще было помочь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTimeFormatter INPUT_DATE_PATTERN = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d HH:mm:ss zz yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTimeFormatter OUTPUT_DATE_PATTERN = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
System.out.println(OUTPUT_DATE_PATTERN.format(INPUT_DATE_PATTERN.parse(date)));
```